# Python - Drop duplicate based on max value of a column

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, group-by, max

I am not really good with pandas, and I think pandas should solve my problem:
I have a text file, that contains data (`id1`;`id2`;`value1`;`value2`;`value3`)

```
1;2;30;40;20.3;
1;2;30;42;26.2;
3;5;12;55;10.7;
3;5;12;23;8.7;
3;5;12;33;11.2;
24;12;1;553;1.1;
24;12;1;23;1.9;
```

As a result, I want to keep lines, that have equal `id1`, `id2`, `value1`, and higher `value3`. `Value2` is not important, but it needs to be kept, e.g.

```
1;2;30;42;26.2;
3;5;12;33;11.2;
24;12;1;23;1.9;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indexes of max value of `value3` and thes select `DataFrame` by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['id1','id2','value1']).value3.idxmax())
id1  id2  value1
1    2    30        1
3    5    12        4
24   12   1         6
Name: value3, dtype: int64

df = df.loc[df.groupby(['id1','id2','value1']).value3.idxmax()]
print (df)
   id1  id2  value1  value2  value3   a
1    1    2      30      42    26.2 NaN
4    3    5      12      33    11.2 NaN
6   24   12       1      23     1.9 NaN
```

Another possible solution is [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `value3` and then `groupby` with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('value3', ascending=False)
       .groupby(['id1','id2','value1'], sort=False)
       .first()
       .reset_index()
print (df)
   id1  id2  value1  value2  value3   a
0    1    2      30      42    26.2 NaN
1    3    5      12      33    11.2 NaN
2   24   12       1      23     1.9 NaN
```