# Python: Get a gene from column B with the highest value, from a group of genes related to each gene in column A

Tags: python, pandas

I have a programming problem that I cannot think up a solution to at the moment. I have a table set up as below:

```
GeneA   GeneB   Value  Distance
1       101     0.9  
1       102     1
1       103     0.8
2       201     1
2       202     1
3       301     0.9
3       302     0.8
3       303     0.8
4       401     1
```

Here, I want to extract, for each gene in the GeneA column, a replacement gene from the GeneB column. The value represents how 'similiar' Gene B is to Gene A, hence I want to get a GeneB with the highest possible value, that is as close to 1 as possible.

In some cases, as with Gene 2, there are genes sharing the same values. Here I would also want to get the genes that have the shortest distance between each other.

How should I go about doing this in Python? Thanks!

EDIT: My intended output is to have a table like below:

```
GeneA   GeneB   Value   Distance
1       102     1
2       201     1
3       301     0.9
4       401     1
```

Where in choosing between 201 or 202 for GeneB, is choosing the one with the shortest distance with GeneA, which was outputted by getting the differences in their genetic positions.

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: Furthermore, how do you define the distance that you are talking about?

Comment: Sure, I've added an expected output to my original post. In terms of distance, it is simply a number based on the difference between the base pair positions of GeneA and GeneB.

Comment: Okay, there one thing I'm not sure about. Do you already have the distance (i.e. it's just missing from your example but you do actually already have it in your dataset)? Or do you intend to compute it with the above data (sorry I'm really not familiar with genetics).

Comment: It's alright! I do actually already have the distance, and I intend to compute it (as its currently in columns as 'PositionA' and 'PositionB'. I wasn't sure how to represent it in the example table so I left it blank. Your solution below looks just about what I needed though, so I shall see if it works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was inspired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267373/python-drop-duplicate-based-on-max-value-of-a-column).

In your case:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'GeneA': [ '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4' ],
'GeneB': [ '101', '102', '103', '201', '202', '301', '302', '303', '401'],
'Value': [ 0.9, 1, 0.8, 1, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 1 ],
})

# Sort by decreasing `Value` and then by decreasing `Distance`
df = df.sort_values(['Value', 'Distance'], ascending=False)

# Group by `GeneA` and select only the first row
df = df.groupby(['GeneA'], sort=False).first()

df

[Out]:
    GeneB   Value
GeneA       
1   102 1.0
2   201 1.0
4   401 1.0
3   301 0.9
```

Comment: df = df.sort_values(['Value', 'Distance'], ascending=False) will sort both Value and Distance in descending.

I guess the requirement is distance should be minimum.
I will suggest one change - 
Pass the ascending parameter as a list [False,True]
This will ensure value is max and distance is min

Comment: Alright, this worked great nonetheless, thanks very much Leopold and Sharad!